# Understanding Git commands

Tags: linux, git

I am trying to understand certain git commands that i saw in .sh file

`git ls-files . --exclude-standard --others -m | wc -l`

From my understanding, this should list all **git files to commit**? from git [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files), exclude standard means

```
--exclude-standard

    Add the standard Git exclusions: .git/info/exclude, .gitignore in each directory, and the user’s global exclusion file.
```

Which I am unsure what this does? like add .gitignore to each directory? also what does `--others -m | wc -l` mean in the above snippet?

also, What does this mean?

```
git ls-files . --exclude-standard --others -m | xargs
git stash push -k -u -- $files_to_stash >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
git checkout --theirs . >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
git stash drop >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Would be super helpful if someone could explain me the above commands and their purpose/use?

Comment: @axiac `git help <command>` and git docs gives definition meaning which I am unable to comprehend.

Comment: `|` is called "pipe". It joins two commands and pipes the output of the first command (`git`) into the input of the second command (`wc -l`). `wc -l` counts the number of lines of its input. Use `man wc` in your terminal for details.

Comment: You should also read the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). It explains the concepts, if you are new to version control systems.

Comment: I like https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=git-ls-files+.+--exclude-standard+--others+-m+%7C+xargs

Comment: @VonC This is marvelous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *lot* (a great deal of stuff) behind all of this.

As [axiac noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59926183/understanding-git-commands#comment105974850_59926183), the `|` character is part of *shell programming*.  Standard Unix / Linux shells, or command-line interpreters, read and execute commands, either from an interactive session or from a script.  The precise details vary from one shell to another, but all of them support the concept of a *pipeline*.  A pipeline connects one command to another command, and Unix / Linux commands have notions of *standard input* and *standard output*.  So:

```
prog1 | prog2 | prog3
```

runs three programs: `prog1` reads its standard input from the keyboard, or wherever the shell's standard input is set right now.  `prog1`'s output is directed into `prog2`, so that when `prog2` reads its standard input, it sees whatever `prog2` printed.  Meanwhile `prog2`'s output is directed into `prog3`, so that when `prog3` reads its standard input, it sees whatever `prog2` has printed.  Since `prog3`'s standard output is *not* redirected, it goes to wherever the shell's standard input is set right now: probably your terminal window.

The `wc` command counts character, words, and lines.  The `-l` argument to `wc` tells it to suppress the character and word counts and print only the line count.

The `git ls-files` command is somewhat complicated.  It can:

- list files that are in Git's *index* (this is the default), or
- list files that *aren't* in Git's index (this is what `--others` selects).

When it does these listings, it can include or exclude files based on various criteria.  In this particular case, the `--others` flag tells it to list files that *are* in the work-tree and are *not* in the index.  The `-m` flag in this particular mode has no meaning and is ignored.  The `--exclude-standard` argument does just what you've quoted: exclude, from the listing output, the names of files that would have been printed, but which meet the standard exclusion criteria.

The standard exclusion criteria are somewhat complicated, as are the notions of *index* and *work-tree* in the first place.  However, to greatly simplify the index—to the point of being wrong in some interesting cases—Git's index is *where you build the next commit you will make*.  Hence `git ls-files --others` lists files that Git *won't* commit: it lists files that are *not* in the index, and Git is going to commit the files that *are* in the index.

The `git ls-files` that you quoted adds `.` to the end, which potentially changes which directories are considered for printing.  However, `git ls-files` defaults to working with `.` anyway, so in this case the `.` is useless, albeit harmless.

Keep in mind that `git stash`, which we'll talk about next, normally operates on the *entire* work-tree, even if you are in some subdirectory within the work-tree.  The `git ls-files` command works the other way: it starts at whatever level you are in, rather than operating from the top.

The `git stash push` command is pretty complicated, especially when used with arguments.  In particular:

> ```
> git stash push -k -u -- $files_to_stash
> ```

writes *three* Git commits instead of the usual two.  A normal `git stash` would then run the equivalent of `git reset --hard` but one with `-k` does something different: it checks out the index copies of the files.  With `-u`, the third commit holds some untracked files.  These options *can* be used independently (though here they are not).

Untracked files are those that are in the work-tree but not in the index, which is just what we were talking about a moment ago with `git ls-files --others`.  However, Git distinguishes between untracked files that are *not* ignored—the `git status` command in particular will *complain* about such files—and untracked files that *are* ignored, where `git status` suppresses the complaint.  The kind of untracked files that `-u` stores are those whose complaints are not to be suppressed, so this `git stash -u` operation applies to the same files we might see in `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard`.

After saving untracked files in the third commit, `git stash` *removes* those files from the work-tree.

When adding specific paths to `git stash`, its operations are limited to those particular paths, except that the index and work-tree commits still contain all files.  It's really more a question of which *version* of which files go into the index and work-tree commits that get made, and are subsequently reset to match `HEAD` (normal operation) or index (`-k` mode).

The first redirection at the end, `>/dev/null`, is a shell construct—it's not part of Git itself.  It tells the shell to send the command's standard output to the file `/dev/null`.  This file itself is special: data written to the file is immediately discarded, and the file remains zero-length.  (You can also read data from `/dev/null`: it appears to contain an infinite number of zero bytes when read, even though its length is zero.)

The `git checkout` command is tremendously complicated—so much so that starting with Git 2.23, it has been split into two separate commands, `git switch` and `git restore`.  The existing `git checkout` command still functions as usual.  It's just easier to *explain and manage* the various operations here when they have been split into two commands.  (This also gives `git restore` the ability to do things that were not possible with a single Git command before.)  The particular one you have asked about, using `--theirs`, invokes a checkout mode that is only useful when the index is storing a *merge conflict*.  In this mode, the index is *not* the proposed next commit: it has been expanded, and committing is forbidden until the merge conflicts are resolved.  This is too big a topic to address here.

The last command, `git stash drop`, directs Git to *discard* a stash (stashes being the two-or-three commit clusters made by `git stash push` or its older synonym, `git stash save`).  This command is a bit dangerous in that once discarded, the stash can be very hard to find.  All of Git's usual "oops I did not mean to forget that commit after all" recovery tricks are in vain with a dropped stash, so be sure that whatever stash you are dropping is *really* no longer needed.